# What are all the possibilities of the calc library to position a point or a line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calc

I know how to draw with the calc library

- a perpendicular line of given length
- a perpendicular line passing through a point
- a line of any angle passing through a point

Are there any other possibilities that I haven't discovered yet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\begin{document}

Une ligne perpendiculaire à une autre de longueur imposée.

A perpendicular line of given length

\begin{tikzpicture}
[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm]

\node [dot=A] at (0,0) {};
\node [dot=B] at (3,1) {};

\draw (A) -- (B)node[dot=C, pos=0.3] (C){} node[dot=D, pos=0.7] (D){};

\draw[red] (C) -- ($(C)!1cm!90:(A)$);

\draw (A) -- (B)node[dot=C, pos=0.3] (C){};

\draw[blue] (D) -- ($(D)!1cm!90:(B)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

Une ligne perpendiculaire passant par un point.

A perpendicular line passing through a point

\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm]

\node [dot=A] at (0,0) {};
\node [dot=B] at (3,1) {};
\node [dot=P] at (1.9,-1.6) {};

\draw [extended line=0.5cm] (A) -- (B);
\draw  ($(A)!(P)!(B)$) -- (P);

\fill [red] ($(A)!(P)!(B)$) circle [radius=2pt];

\end{tikzpicture}

Une ligne avec un angle quelconque de longueur imposée.

A line of any angle passing through a point of imposed length


\begin{tikzpicture}
[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm]

\node [dot=A] at (0,0) {};
\node [dot=B] at (3,1) {};

\draw (A) -- (B)node[dot=C, pos=0.3] (C){} node[dot=D, pos=0.7] (D){};

\draw[red] (C) -- ($(C)!1cm!45:(A)$);

\draw[blue] (D) -- ($(D)!2cm!30:(B)$);
\draw[blue] (D) -- ($(D)!2cm!-60:(B)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The [manual](https://tikz.dev/tikz-coordinates#sec-13.5) describes the possibilities relatively well. It also has factors `($2 * (3, 2)$)` and vector additions `($(1, 2) + (3, 4)$)`. And of course, you can combine all of them.

Comment: THANKS
I was rather looking for tricks of particular layouts like those quoted in the question:
parallel line, tangent to a curve, ...